# How to use Comparator<T> as an argument in a generic SortedDoublyLinkedList

Tags: java, generics, comparator, doubly-linked-list

I am currently working on an assignment for class where I am tasked with creating an empty List that has a Comparator as an argument then creating an add method for that sortedDoublyLinkedList where I am passed an argument and I have to iterate through the list to find where the new node fits. I'm not very familiar with Comparator so I'm a bit clueless as to how to add elements to my DoublyLinkedList because I cannot access the Comparator the way I though I was supposed to. Here is what I have now. Here is what I currently have.

```
public class SortedDoubleLinkedList<T> extends BasicDoubleLinkedList<T> {

    Node<T> head=null;
    Node<T> tail=null;
    SortedDoubleLinkedList<T> sDLL;

    public SortedDoubleLinkedList(Comparator<T> comparator2){
        sDLL=new SortedDoubleLinkedList<T>(comparator2);
    }
    public SortedDoubleLinkedList<T> add(T data){

        Node<T> newNode=new Node<T>(data);

        //I have to iterate through the list and find where the new element data         fits
        if(head!=null&&tail!=null) {
            Node<T> cursor=head;
            while(cursor!=null) {
                //the following code doesn't work
                if(sDLL.comparator2.compare(data, cursor.getData())==0) {

                }

            }

        }
        else {
            head=newNode;
            tail=newNode;
        }
        return this; //return the SortedDoubleLinkedList<T>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparator is an interface. You need to implement a class that will provide that interface.

```
class Whatever implements Comparator<TYPE> {
   int compare(TYPE a, TYPE b) {
      ... code to decide whether a is less than,
          equal to, or greater than b ...
   }
}
```

Where I wrote TYPE, you need an actual type.  Just supplying the type variable T is not going to get you to runnable code, which I assume is your goal.  Ultimately you've got to say *what* type will go in your list.   So I'd be expecting something like (in your code above)

```
public class SortedDoubleLinkedList extends BasicDoubleLinkedList<String> {
```

where you're storing Strings in your list. And then TYPE in my code is also String.

ALTERNATIVELY

You can leave your SortedDoubleLinkedList generic (in terms of T) but ultimately you want to get concrete about it, maybe

```
SortedDoubleLinkedList<String> = new SortedDoubleLinkedList(new Whatever());
```

but the `Comparator` is still going to need to be a `Comparator<String>` (or whatever type you choose).